# "If it was raining" vs "If it had been raining"

Tags: difference

My non-native English-speaking friend asked me the question, and I said one way, but her other native English-speaking friend said the opposite and I wanted to hear other opinions.

She asked, which of these is better (imagining you're on the top of a mountain):

> We couldn't have come here if it was raining.

vs

> We couldn't have come here if it had been raining.

I said I prefer the second, her other English-speaking friend said they prefer the first. Is there a difference? Are they both acceptable? Is it a regional difference?

Comment: The second version is more grammatically correct. Some people might use the first one in casual speech and it would be understood.

Comment: Can we assume it's still not raining?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. But how?

These sentences both use "unreal" grammar. The reason they're both correct will make more sense if we change them back to real sentences with the same meaning:

> (1) We **have been** able to come here because it isn't raining.
>
> (2) We **were** able to come here because it wasn't raining.

Sentence (1) refers to the **present** situation of now being at the top of the mountain, and the **present** fact that it's not raining. Sentence (2) refers to the **past** situation of arriving at the top of the mountain with the **past** reason why. So it's two perspectives on the same thing: either (1) *now being* at the top of the mountain, or (2) *having arrived earlier*.

I've highlighted the two main verbs. You'll notice they don't have the same tense, even though the original two sentences have the exact same structure*. This is because when we shift present perfect or simple past into "unreal" grammar, *the result is the same*: *"could have" + past participle*.

<sub>*I've also replaced "couldn't" with "be able to" for grammar reasons which are unrelated to this question.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, it depends on the time. You say the second one, for instance, when you tell this memory to a friend a year later because it's the third conditional. It's explained on British Council Learn English website as;

''The third conditional is used to imagine a different past. We imagine a change in a past situation and the different result of that change.''

Answer (score 1):

The simple past ("was") is used to discuss possibilities. The past perfect ("had been") is used to discuss counterfactuals. That is, if you're uncertain about whether something happened, and want to discuss the consequences of it being the case, the simple past is appropriate. For instance, "If it was raining, they will be late". If you know something didn't happen, but want to discuss a hypothetical world in which it did happen, the past perfect is correct.

Answer (score 0):

One does not say, "If it was..", but "If it were..." This is the subjunctive mood, used in stating a condition *known* to be false.

[Tevye is grammatically correct](https://genius.com/Topol-if-i-were-a-rich-man-lyrics) asking, "If I were a rich man."

Comment: That rule was a *prescriptive* one, and now [isn't a rule at all](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+I+were%2Cif+I+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20were%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20was%3B%2Cc0). When [Gwen Stefani covered that same song](https://genius.com/Gwen-stefani-rich-girl-lyrics) in 2004, she deliberately changed the grammar to "*If I **was** a rich girl*". I've always felt she made that choice because "If I were..." was an old rule falling by the wayside, and using "If I was..." made her sound more modern.

Comment: @gotube, Grammar often is used to differentiate people, whether rightly or wrongly. If one teaches students to use the vernacular, it can impact application for school and jobs. "Ain't" *is* in the dictionary, but should be avoided in formal use. For the same reason, an English learner should be taught *-commonly accepted* usage.

Comment: I heartily agree with every word you said. I think you and I disagree about whether "*If I **was**...*" is still vernacular, and I'm fine with that. :)

Comment: For what it's worth, some standard ESL textbooks teach that both are acceptable, like Grammar In Use Intermediate 4th edition.